# Safely display html encoded values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, xss

Assuming I have the following string:

```
Frozen Synapse &#8211; A Business Mini-Postmortem!
```

Is there a way to white list specific html encoded values or should I just perform:

```
string.gsub('&#8211;', '-')
```

to produce the desired output in an HTML view:

```
Frozen Synapse – A Business Mini-Postmortem!
```

**Edit**: there may be other html in the string that I don't want to allow.  I want to white list certain html encoded characters (like a dash).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `html_safe` method in your view. E.g.

```
<%="Frozen Synapse &#8211; A Business Mini-Postmortem!".html_safe%>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow arbitrary html to be rendered?  Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question - I don't necessarily know what might be in the string but I would like specific html encoded characters through.